# ACME certificates in Mailcow (bypassing Traefik)

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to run mailcow (in a docker) behind Traefik. Mailcow itself is accessible, Sogo's webmail works fine, etc... but Let's Encrypt challenge is getting answered by Traefik instead of Mailcow, thus drawing Mailcow's ACMEs invalid.

Is there a way I can make Traefik bypass the acme challenges and allow Mailcow to handle them?

Comment: Did you already found a solution? I'll try to get Traefik working along with poste.io for mail delivery

Answer (score 0):

As your traefik.toml is most likely something like this..

```
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "XXX"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "XXX"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

..just comment the acme part (only the challange part would also be enough) like the following.

```
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "XXX"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

#[acme]
#email = "XXX"
#storage = "acme.json"
#entryPoint = "https"
#onHostRule = true
#[acme.httpChallenge]
#entryPoint = "http"
```

This results in traefik not answering any acme challanges anymore. After creating the certificates through the mailcow acme container you might want to enable traefiks acme again.